# Using add-ons for commercial use

Tags: add-on

Can I use any blender add-on commercially? I've done some research on the topic, but it seems kind of confusing. Blender comes with pre-installed add-ons which are made by developers and the community. Can I use these add-ons for any purpose. What about add-ons from the web? From what I can gather, once your get the add-on, you can use it for whatever purpose, but I would really like a clear answer.

Comment: Yes, you can use the pre-installed addons commercially. Third-party addons should come with their own license, but I have yet to encounter a Blender addon that forbids commercial use.

Comment: @Leander Can addon developer forbid commercial usage? [License — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/about/license/). Or they need to make commercial license under the core script which doesn't use any Blender API (how?). Or the statement on official webpage is only for built-in addon?

Comment: They can't forbid it. Blender and its addons is under GPL. And this means every user of the software, or an addon, is allowed to use and modify it in the way he wants as long as he does not violate the GPL.

Answer (score 2):

[FAQ — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/support/faq/#using-blender)

> ### Can I use Blender commercially?
>
> Yes you can. Any creation you make as an artist with Blender is your sole property, and can be applied for any purpose you choose to. This also applies the Add-ons and Python scripts you write for Blender.
>
> If you like to distribute Blender itself, you have to be aware of the GPL rules, which basically means you have to make sources for Blender available as well. However, in general it’s sufficient to provide information that forwards to blender.org.

All software nowadays should contain licenses, no exception for Blender. [License — blender.org](https://www.blender.org/about/license/), which the licenses of Blender **itself** is *basically* using GNU V2 and V3 but some of the component is a slightly strict license. eg. *Cycles*: [Apache 2.0](https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0)

If your usage contain any modification of Blender **and redistribute** it with commercial license, it will probably cause some problem since that's not what GNU wanted. But if your just using Blender to creating content, it will be fine.

And there's also an interest point is that, **Sharing Blender or Blender add-ons or scripts is always OK and not considered piracy.**

Comment: It is not this easy. Things like manual and additional content like images may not be under GPL. And you are not allowed to redistribute this content with the addon then. Usually just the source code is under GPL.

Comment: @Tiles So in practice, addon can be protected by making it hard to use without additional content?

Comment: Depends. But yeah, when you bundle an addon with let's say image functionality, and put the images under its own license, then you can just distribute the code, but not the images ... That's at least how i know it.